# How to speed up Merge Statement in Azure (processing 44,000 records)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have code which peforms a merge from a table variable type into a table on an Azure SQL Database. This database was created on Azure pay as you go.

Now i have some JSON which gets loaded into a table variable after which a MERGE is done.

Now the base table has 144, 000 records and im selecting (via a ChannelID), 44,000 records to merge into my destination table.

This is taking up to 4 seconds on Azure...where as on my local SQL Server instance , it takes less than half a second.

why should it take so long to load in a relatively small amount of data?

Im attaching the query exeuction plan for this here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJJBCS_-h

The query is as follows:

```sql
select  @JSON  = [JSON]  from [dbo].[ChannelReadingJSON]
 where SerialNumber = 939029 and TimeStamp = '2023-03-23 16:48:52.1366667'

INSERT INTO @ChannelReadings ([SerialNumber],[ChannelID],[Si],[Raw], [Conversion],[TimeStamp])

 SELECT device.DeviceSerialNumber,
           Readings.ChannelId,
           channel_list.Si,
           channel_list.Raw,
           channel_list.Conversion,
           channel_list.TimeStamp

    FROM
        OPENJSON(@JSON)
                 WITH
                     (
                     ChannelReadings        NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.ChannelReadings' AS JSON,
                     DeviceSerialNumber     NVARCHAR(100) '$.DeviceSerialNumber'
                     ) AS device
            OUTER APPLY
        OPENJSON(device.ChannelReadings)
                 WITH
                     (
                     ChannelId              INT '$.ChannelId',
                     DataHashDto            NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.DataHashDto',
                     ReadingsDto            NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.ReadingsDto' AS JSON
                     ) AS Readings
            OUTER APPLY
        OPENJSON(Readings.ReadingsDto)
                 WITH
                     (
                     Si                     DECIMAL(10, 2),
                     [Raw]                  DECIMAL(10, 2),
                     Conversion             INT,
                     [TimeStamp]            DATETIME
                     ) channel_list

MERGE [ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F] T
 USING
                                (
                                    SELECT 
                                       [Si]   as SIReading,
                                       [Raw]  as RawReading,
                                       [TimeStamp] as ReadingDateTime
                                   FROM
                                        @tt
                                   WHERE 
                                        ChannelID = '11'
   ) S  on T.ReadingDateTime = S.ReadingDateTime  
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
 THEN 
 INSERT (ReadingDateTime,SIReading, RawReading)
 VALUES (S.ReadingDateTime,S.SIReading, S.RawReading);
```

The table definitions are

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F](
 [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [ChannelID] [tinyint] NULL,
 [Si] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 [Raw] [int] NULL,
 [ReadingDateTime] [datetime] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20230403-100008]
ON [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F] (
 [ReadingDateTime] ASC
 )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ChannelReadingType] AS TABLE(
 [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [ChannelID] [TINYINT] NULL,
 [Si] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 [Raw] [int] NULL,
 [ReadingDateTime] [datetime] NULL
 )
GO
```

Comment: Why are you using a `MERGE` and not an `INSERT` (with a `NOT EXISTS) when you have no `WHEN MATCHED` clause? The plan also shows that a scan is needed on your table; is your table `ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F` indexed? What are the definition(s) of the index(es)?

Comment: Please show the table defintion *including indexes*, also the definition of the table variables. Also what is the relevance of the insert to the merge, they seem to be different tables?

Comment: Side note: *Rows* not "records".

Comment: The definition of the Table is as follows:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F](
 [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [ChannelID] [tinyint] NULL,
 [Si] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 [Raw] [int] NULL,
 [ReadingDateTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: This is the Index defintion 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20230403-100008] ON [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F]
(
 [ReadingDateTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
GO

Comment: And this is the definition of the table variable

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS [dbo].[ChannelReadingType]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[ChannelReadingType]    Script Date: 03/04/2023 15:41:32 ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ChannelReadingType] AS TABLE(
 [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [ChannelID] [TINYINT] NULL,
 [Si] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 [Raw] [int] NULL,
 [ReadingDateTime] [datetime] NULL
)
GO

Comment: You should have edited that into your question, I've done that now. What about `@tt`

Comment: "This is taking up to 4 seconds on Azure...where as on my local SQL Server instance , it takes less than half a second." - that could be related to the tier disk you have on the database and storage account (premium vs standard) and have nothing to do with the code.  I think you indicate standard storage in your comment in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following indexes

```sql
ChannelReadingJSON (SerialNumber, TimeStamp) INCLUDE (JSON)  -- either clustered or non-clustered
```

```
DROP INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20230403-100008]
ON [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F];

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20230403-100008]
ON [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F] (
 [ReadingDateTime] ASC
 );
```

You should think about which column should be the primary key, and whether any should be nullable (probably not).

And for the table type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ChannelReadingType] AS TABLE(
 [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [ChannelID] [TINYINT] NULL,
 [Si] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 [Raw] [int] NULL,
 [ReadingDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CLUSTERED INDEX IX (ReadingDateTime)
 )
```

Consider replacing the `MERGE` with a `INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```sql
INSERT T (ReadingDateTime,SIReading, RawReading)
SELECT S.TimeStamp, S.SI, S.Raw
FROM @tt tt
WHERE tt.ChannelID = '11'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM T WITH (HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE T.ReadingDateTime = S.ReadingDateTime  
);
```

Comment: So I made those adjustments which were creating a Clustered index on [ReadingDateTime] on both the table [dbo].[ChannelReading_939029_11_F0EA4CCA-3522-4175-AA53-83563F91235F]  and the table variable type  [dbo].[ChannelReadingType] 

I then ran the code ...replacing the MERGE with INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS but this is taking 5 seconds now to run

Comment: Can you share an execution plan

Comment: Sure here is my Execution Plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkHTx3Fbh

Comment: Not sure there is much else to do, it's just a lot of rows.

Comment: Do you think switching to the next Tier may help?
im working on pay as you go... 
Details as follows:
Pricing tier:  Standard S0: 10 DTUS

Maximum Storage Size:  250 GB

Comment: 10 DTUs doesn't sound much, but not got much info on that.